# Why is ZSH preforming string editing with`:r` present in a string

Tags: unix, zsh

While doing some scripting I came across some unexpected behaviour for string interpolation, that I would love to get to the bottom of understanding why this is happening, please!

From the outputs shown bellow, ZSH seems to be doing some string editing that would not be the intended behaviour.

Once `:r` is present in the string, this seems to be acting as an operator and so is not forming part of the string as expected. I would have expected to remain as part of the string.

I am aware that `:r` is old c-shell string removal (see [here](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch28_05.htm) for reference), is that what is going on? More importantly, why is my terminal picking this up?

Here is the ZSH output with the unexpected behaviour:

```zsh
conorhennessy@Cs-MacBook-Pro ~ % export test=123456
conorhennessy@Cs-MacBook-Pro ~ % echo $test
123456
conorhennessy@Cs-MacBook-Pro ~ % echo "$test"
123456
conorhennessy@Cs-MacBook-Pro ~ % echo "$test:r"
123456
conorhennessy@Cs-MacBook-Pro ~ % echo "$test:ro"
123456o
conorhennessy@Cs-MacBook-Pro ~ % echo "$test:role"
123456ole
conorhennessy@Cs-MacBook-Pro ~ % echo $test
123456
conorhennessy@Cs-MacBook-Pro ~ % echo $test:r
123456
conorhennessy@Cs-MacBook-Pro ~ % echo $test:ro
123456o
conorhennessy@Cs-MacBook-Pro ~ % echo $test:role
123456ole
conorhennessy@Cs-MacBook-Pro ~ % echo '$test'
$test
```

For comparison, here is the Bash output which behaves as expected:

```bash
conorhennessy@Cs-MacBook-Pro ~ % bash
bash-3.2$ test=123465
bash-3.2$ echo $test
123465
bash-3.2$ echo "$test"
123465
bash-3.2$ echo "$test:r"
123465:r
bash-3.2$ echo "$test:ro"
123465:ro
bash-3.2$ echo "$test:role"
123465:role
```

Regarding my environment, here are some details:
I performed all these actions in iTerm2 Build 3.4.10
I am running zsh 5.8 x86_64-apple-darwin20.0 on MacOS Big Sur version 11.6 (20G165)
`uname -a` results in:
`` Darwin Cs-MacBook-Pro.local 20.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Mon Aug 30 06:12:21 P`DT 2021; root:xnu-7195.141.6~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 ``

Comment: If I should provide more about my environment, rephrase or clarify anything please do say.

Comment: It does, clearly my Googling did not go far enough! Thank you, I will update the answer here appropriately - I think that would be a good idea rather than deleting as my question provides some examples and comparison.

Comment: Duplicates aren't deleted, UrbanConor -- they're simply linked to the other question(s), so there's no need to post an answer here on this question. In fact, your copied answer could become out-of-date if the linked answer changes, so it's better to *not* duplicate answers here.

Comment: Please don't spam tags. Your question has nothing with [tag:bash] or [tag:macos] or [tag:iterm2] to do; the behavior you are asking about is specific to [tag:zsh] but obviously occurs on any platform.

Comment: Ahh good to know Jeff, I have removed my answer so that it doesn't become out of date. Thanks for letting me know how it works, now I know!

Pardon my ignorance tripleee. You are indeed correct but at the time of asking and applying the tags, I was unaware of what the behaviour I was asking about and so that is why I applied the tags. I am glad that the irrelevant ones have now been removed. My apologies :)